# Error on git push to Heroku with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git

When I perform a git push to a repository on Heroku I receive the following error:

```
'Firing branch removed and pull event' has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during: 'Firing branch removed and pull event'.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I tried googling it and was unsuccessful. Can anyone help?

The output of `git remote -v` is:

```
heroku git@heroku.com:growing-night-6166.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:growing-night-6166.git (push) 
origin git@github.com:stuartnelson3/sample_app.git (fetch) 
origin git@github.com:stuartnelson3/sample_app.git (push)
```

Comment: Never seen this, but did you set your tracking branch?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException` suggests that your problem is neither with `git` or with `ruby`.  What are you running that is using Java?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not running anything that uses Java. I haven't intentionally turned on anything that uses Java, and I suppose a tip off that it isn't affecting git would be that my pushes are still going through successfully. Also, how do I set my tracking branch?

Comment: Well, *something* is obviously using java.  What are you pushing to?

Comment: just git, regular old "git push" command.

Comment: Sorry, *to what remote repository are you pushing*?  What does `git remote -v` show?  Are you pushing to something on your local host? Something hosted remotely?  By another group at your organization?  By a commercial hosting service?

Comment: `heroku git@heroku.com:growing-night-6166.git (fetch)`          `heroku git@heroku.com:growing-night-6166.git (push)`    
`origin git@github.com:stuartnelson3/sample_app.git (fetch)`    
`origin git@github.com:stuartnelson3/sample_app.git (push)`

Comment: Note that it is generally more helpful to add the output to your question.  I've done that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two remotes specified for your repository; one on github and one on heroku.  Which one do you expect `git push` to contact?

With a standard configuration, typing `git push` will push to the remote named `origin`, which in your case is at Github.

To push explicitly push the `master` branch to Heroku you would type:

```
git push heroku master
```

Per-branch configuration in your repository may change the default behavior.  Assuming that you are working on the `master` branch, you can see where a bare `git push` will send things by running this command:

```
git config --get-regexp 'branch.master.*'
```

Which will show something like this:

```
branch.master.remote origin
branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

This will tell you whether your `git push` is trying to contact Github or Heroku.  In either case, it looks like a problem on the remote end and I would contact support at the appropriate organization.

Let us know to which remote you're trying to push and we can try to do something additional diagnosis.

Comment: I'm wanting `git push` to send to github and `git push heroku` to push to heroku; do i need to specify `git push heroku master` each time or is it assumed that it will push whatever branch i'm working in?

Comment: By default `git push` will push *matching* branches (branches that have the same name on the remote as in the local repository).  So after successfully running `git push heroku master` once, you should then be able to simply run `git push heroku` and it will push the `master` branch.